# Extract the first letter of a UTF-8 string with Lua

Tags: unicode, utf-8, lua

Is there any way to extract the first letter of a UTF-8 encoded string with Lua?

Lua does not properly support Unicode, so `string.sub("ÆØÅ", 2, 2)` will return `"?"` rather than `"Ø"`.

Is there a relatively simple UTF-8 parsing algorithm I could use on the string byte per byte, for the sole purpose of getting the first letter of the string, be it a Chinese character or an A?

Or is this way too complex, requiring a huge library, etc.?

Comment: "*simple Unicode parsing algorithm*" What *kind* of "Unicode" is this? Is it UTF-8, UTF-16, something else? What's the encoding?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html Read this. Please.

Comment: Here's also a [page for Lua users](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can easily extract the first letter from a UTF-8 encoded string with the following code:

```
function firstLetter(str)
  return str:match("[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*")
end
```

Because a UTF-8 code point either begins with a byte from 0 to 127, or with a byte from 194 to 244 followed by one or several bytes from 128 to 191.

You can even *iterate* over UTF-8 code points in a similar manner:

```
for code in str:gmatch("[%z\1-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*") do
  print(code)
end
```

Note that both examples return a *string* value for each letter, and not the Unicode code point numerical value.

Comment: Brilliant! This was exactly the answer I was looking for. Short and precise.

Comment: This is reasonable for data that's already been validated but you might want to be careful with data which hasn't been.

Answer (score 6):

Lua 5.3 provide a [UTF-8 library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.5).

You can use `utf8.codes` to get each code point, and then use `utf8.char` to get the character:

```
local str = "ÆØÅ"
for _, c in utf8.codes(str) do
  print(utf8.char(c))
end
```

---

This also works:

```
local str = "ÆØÅ"
for w in str:gmatch(utf8.charpattern ) do
  print(w)
end
```

where `utf8.charpattern` is just the string `"[\0-\x7F\xC2-\xF4][\x80-\xBF]*"` for the pattern to match one UTF-8 byte sequence.