# string.sub in Corona Lua crashes with ÅÄÖ

Tags: lua, coronasdk

this snippet crashes my simulator bad.

```
s = "stämma"
s1 =  string.sub(s,3,3)
print(s1)
```

It seems like it handles my character as nil, any ideas?

Joakim

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using UTF-8 encoding.

In UTF-8, a character can have a variable number of bytes, between 1 to 4. The `"ä"` character (228) is encoded with the two bytes `0xC3 0xA4`.

The instruction `string.sub(s, 3, 3)` returns the third *byte* from the string (`0xC3`), and **not** the third character. As this byte alone is invalid UTF-8, Corona can't display the character.

See also [Extract the first letter of a UTF-8 string with Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235091)