# how to write a lua pattern for words with umlauts

Tags: design-patterns, lua

Words like "Annähren", "Überbringen", "Malmö" are not catched by

```
for w in string.gmatch(str, "%w+") do
     print(w) 
end
```

Any solution? thanks!

Comment: Can you try "%S+". I remember reading somewhere that %S represents every char that is NOT space. So : `for w in string.gmatch(str, "%S+")`

Comment: That's close to my (hopefully) final solution: 
`for w in string.gmatch(myStr, "[^,;]+") do print(w) 
end` That works for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

The Lua string library does not intrinsically support any character encoding other than ASCII, and assumes all characters are 1 byte. While lua strings are 8-bit clean, this means that functions like `string.sub` expect offsets in bytes even in multi-byte character encodings, and functions like `string.match` will not behave as expected with non-ASCII encodings. It is worth reading the [wiki page on Unicode in Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode), much of which also applies to other non-ASCII character encodings.

For your issue in particular, 'ö' is (in, for example, UTF-8) encoded as the two bytes `C3 B6`, which means that it will not be recognized by `'%w'` (which looks for characters in the a-z range, and has no concept of characters spanning multiple bytes). `'[\xc3\xb6]+'` will match it, but will also match a lot of other things, not all of which are even valid UTF-8 - and using `'[ö]'` has the same issue, as lua will interpret it as the same thing (a sequence of two bytes rather than a single character). If you are not using UTF-8, the specifics are different, but the basic problem remains the same.

The wiki page links a number of UTF-8 aware string library implementations for lua, such as [slnunicode](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/sln/slnunicode). Other encodings do not appear to be widely used by the community, so if you are using an encoding other than UTF-8, your best bet may to be convert to UTF-8 and then use that library or another like it.

Comment: In practice, you are basically correct. The Lua spec (and source code) don't require any particular character set and encoding. The behavior of a few functions in Lua's `string` library depends on the the C runtime library (or equiv) that it is built for. Lua builders should provide their users with technical data on character sets, number characteristics, etc. **The `string` data type is a counted sequence of bytes, not a sequence of characters.**

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
local str = "Annähren, Überbringen, Malmö"
for w in string.gmatch(str, "[%w\128-\244]+") do
  print(w) 
end
```

It's not strictly correct as it ignores some UTF-8 combinations, but it may work for you. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13238257/1442917) and this [post on validating UTF-8](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/fixing-malformed-utf8-in-lua) may be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is working with UTF-8. It might be some extended ASCII encoding, thus extending the range up to `\255` could be needed (or adding the specific char codes, if the OP can find out which they are).

Comment: Could be; I'm not sure either. That's why I said "may try" ;)

Comment: Yep! That's why I felt like adding that hint. :-)

Comment: If one has a text file or string (including Lua source) and doesn't know the character set and encoding, then one has experienced *data loss.* If one knows the character set and encoding of the data but doesn't know if the functions to be used are compatible with it then one is [programming by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence).