# Arabic text to array of letters using string.gmatch in Corona SDK

Tags: android, ios, sdk, lua, coronasdk

Please help

I'm trying to send arabic text to array of arabic letters using string.gmatch in corona sdk so please help to do it right

```
local lArray={}
local t="من جد وجد ومن زرع حصد"
for value in string.gmatch(t,".") do 
lArray [index] = value
print(value)
index = index + 1
end
```

The output is this character

```
2013-12-25 22:48:01.337 Corona Simulator[4878:507] Ù
2013-12-25 22:48:01.337 Corona Simulator[4878:507] …
2013-12-25 22:48:01.337 Corona Simulator[4878:507] Ù
2013-12-25 22:48:01.338 Corona Simulator[4878:507] †
```

appreciate your help

---

I found this solution in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235091/extract-the-first-letter-of-a-utf-8-string-with-lua)

Comment: [I found this solution it helped me to resolve the issue ][1] 
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235091/extract-the-first-letter-of-a-utf-8-string-with-lua

Answer (score 0):

Unless Corona has added it, pattern matching in Lua does nor support Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `utf8` plugin
https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/utf8/index.html

```
string.gmatch( s, pattern )

s:gmatch( pattern )
```